# Do session attributes show in URL when handling post redirect in Spring MVC 3?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3, httpsession, post-redirect-get

I am handling forms in Spring MVC and I submitted a form and I am trying to redirect the post request to avoid resubmitting the form with refresh button.

But I need a dynamically generated value to be displayed based on the form submission in the redirected page. So I am saving that value in session in the post handler method and getting it back in the redirected page handling method.

Would I get the session attribute shown displayed in the redirected page like request parameters in GET method case?

Following is the code that I am using:

**This method is handling the form submission**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String testStopped(Model model, WebRequest request, HttpSession session) {
    //...
    int foo = 1234;//some dynamically generated value
    session.setAttribute("foo", foo);
    return "redirect:/something/somethingelse";
}
```

**This method is handling the redirected page**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something/somethingelse") 
public String testStopped(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    ...
    Integer kungfoo = (Integer) session.getAttribute("foo");
    model.addAttribute("kungfoo", kungfoo);
    return "somethingelse";
}
```

This is the url I end up with after redirect: http://wikedlynotsmart.com/something/somethingelse?kungfoo=1234

Is there a way to for `?kungfoo=1234` not to be displayed at the end and still get it passed to the redirect request handler method?

Is this how it is supposed to work or I am committing a blunder somewhere? Could someone help me understand it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-ann-redirect-attributes):

> By default all model attributes are considered to be exposed as URI
>   template variables in the redirect URL. Of the remaining attributes
>   those that are primitive types or collections/arrays of primitive
>   types are automatically appended as query parameters.

This means that kungfoo is an attribute of your model in the first method, and that it's thus automatically added as a request param to the redirect URL.

The rest of the paragraph explains how to proceed if you don't want all the attributes in the redirect URL (although I have the feeling that the default is exactly what you should use, in this case, since you want the second request to get back the kungfoo value):

> In annotated controllers however the model may contain additional
>   attributes originally added for rendering purposes (e.g. drop-down
>   field values). To gain precise control over the attributes used in a
>   redirect scenario, an @RequestMapping method can declare an argument
>   of type RedirectAttributes and use it to add attributes for use in
>   RedirectView. If the controller method does redirect, the content of
>   RedirectAttributes is used. Otherwise the content of the default Model
>   is used.

If you want to stay with this solution of storing the value in the session, you should use a flash attribute, so it's removed from the session as soon as the second request is received. The rest of the paragraph explains how to use them.

Comment: Yes, I meant in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me:

Adding an argument of type `RedirectAttributes` and adding `foo` as a flash attribute to it.

**This method is handling the form submission**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String testStopped(Model model, WebRequest request, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    //...
    int foo = 1234;
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("foo", foo);
    return "redirect:/something/somethingelse";
}
```

**This method is handling the redirected page; nothing needs to be done here for "foo"**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something/somethingelse") 
public String testStopped() {
    return "somethingelse";
}
```

**This is how you use "foo" in somethingelse.jsp**

```
${foo}
```

And http://wikedlynotsmart.com/somethingelse is what I get in the URL.

Comment: There is one issue with this though. If I refresh the redirected page, `foo` gets disappeared.

Comment: @_skip: check this out, at the bottom of this [page](http://www.tikalk.com/java/redirectattributes-new-feature-spring-mvc-31).